# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of special matrix $A=u u^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the special matrix $A=u u^T$, where $u \in R^n$.

I wrote down the matrix, which is the linear combination of vector $u$ by itself, and clearly has zero as a determinant, so I don't know how to continue.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to compute $Au$ and note that $u^Tu$ is a number. Also argue that $A$ has an $(n-1)$-dimensional kernel.

Comment: $u$ is an eigenvector, and so is anything orthogonal to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Observe that$$Au=uu^Tu=|u|^2u$$and $$\forall w,w^Tu=0\to Aw=uu^Tw=0$$

Comment: Nice! So $||u||^2$ is an eigenvalue and $u$ is the eigenvector, but I don't understand the second line !

Comment: That's right. The second line implies that another eigenvalue of the matrix $A$ is zero with its eigenvectors being **all** orthogonal to $u$ (which also states that the multiplicity of its $0$-value eigenvalue is $n-1$)